# Qt plugin options for configuring

Tags: qt, qmake, qtplugin, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am trying to build qtvirtualkeyboard plugin following [this instructions](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-build.html) with `arrow-key-navigation` option enabled. But I don't understand how to enable it in the right way. I have tried to add

```
CONFIG += arrow-key-navigation
```

into `qtvirtualkeyboard.pro` without any success. When I add

```
DEFINES += QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_ARROW_KEY_NAVIGATION
```

into `src/virtualkeyboard/virtualkeyboard.pro` it works, but I think this is the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources should be pristine and you shouldn't be touching them. Delete the decompressed sources, and reinstall them.

The configuration options are passed to `qmake`, on the command line. E.g., assuming an out-of-source build (the only sane way!):

```
qmake /path/to/qtvirtualkeyboard.pro CONFIG+=arrow-key-navigation
```

These options can be specified in Qt Creator's build settings: there's a place to add `qmake` command line options to.

Comment: Can you enabled/disable the `BaseKey`'s like this as well?